# Add a Footer and Navigation to React app in the App.js file, including react routing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a Footer to my App.js. I have already added the Navigation to the App.js file. I am wanting to add the Footer to every page instead of adding it onto the bottom of every page I make.

**App.js** file

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import DocumentTitle from "react-document-title";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import NoMatch from "./components/NoMatch";
import Landing from "./components/Landing";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

function App() {
  return (
    <DocumentTitle title="Page Title">
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navigation />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
          {/*  This Footer placement doesn't work  */}
          <Footer /> 
        </div>
      </Router>
    </DocumentTitle>
  );
}`
```

Every time I place the `<Footer />` somewhere.. the DOM crashes. Here is an example of what I am receiving...

**Error**

> ×
> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `App`.

Attached is a Footer.js and Navigation.js file for ease..

**Footer.js**

```
import React from "react";

function Footer() {
  return (
    <div>
      <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

**Navigation.js**

```
import React from "react";

function Navigation() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Navbar</h1>
    </div>
   );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: I am not sure what's causing the problem, but my concern is that some other import might be causing a conflict. I would typically try to mess up a little with the naming to see if it changes anything. For example rename the `Footer` component to `MyFooter`, import with a different name maybe `import MySuperFooter` from '...'. Let me know if it changes anything.

Comment: I have imported your code in a Code Sandbox project and everything is fine there. Did you included the content of all files? Maybe some file can be blank... Take a look in the project in: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-heisenberg-l8vuw

Comment: So usually when the export is messed up it will say 'but got: undefined.' but in your case it says 'but got: object.'  Meaning your export is not a class/function/string.  I would try adding a console.log to the app.js file and see what it shows.  I did it here is this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-wildflower-268i3?file=/src/App.js) an it shows function and works fine.

Comment: Yeah, I built the app too and it works, I didn't have your other components, so I just changed the routes to all point to the footer and it worked fine...  Must be something not in the Navigation nor the Footer.  All the above looks good, I think..

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I went by each one and tried figuring out the issue. The answer is being posted.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this tedious question lay within the exportation of the component. The component was not exported correctly. I corrected that by using my way of exporting the footer component folder.

The component index.js was empty, so I just added `export { default } from "./Footer";`

Thank you all for your answers.